# Django Dynamic Forms ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a problem that I want to make a football league page that can submit the starting XI list.

But I don't know how to build the Dynamic Form.

User (which is the team owner) can Login to choose the match to upload the starting XI.
Website will show up the player list of the Team and let the User select Max of 11 and submit.

The important thing is

1. How can I generate the form with the Players belongs to Team.
2. How to let the User upload Home / Away (The team belongs to User) starting XI only.

**Model.py**

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    schedule_name = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=LEAGUE_CHOICES, default='nil')
    schedule_home = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',related_name='schedule_home')
    schedule_away = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',related_name='schedule_away')

class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    player_name = models.CharField('Player Name', max_length=30, unique=True)
    player_team = models.ForeignKey(Team ,on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=1)

class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField('Team Name', max_length=30, unique=True)
    team_owner = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='owner')

class Match_Starting(models.Model):
    starting_schedule = models.OneToOneField(Schedule,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    home_starting = models.ManyToManyField(Player,blank=True,related_name='home_starting')
    away_starting = models.ManyToManyField(Player,blank=True,related_name='away_starting')

@receiver(post_save, sender=Schedule)
    def create_match_stat(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Match_Starting.objects.create(starting_schedule=instance)
```

**Forms.py**

```
class MatchStartingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Match_Starting
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Views.py**

```
@login_required
def update_starting(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        try:
            selected_team = Team.objects.get(team_owner=request.user)
        except:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    if request.method == 'GET':
        selected_player = Player.objects.filter(player_team=selected_team).order_by('player_name')
        team_schedule_list = Schedule.objects.filter(schedule_time__lte=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(weeks=1),schedule_time__gte=datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)).filter(Q(schedule_home__team_name=selected_team)|Q(schedule_away__team_name=selected_team))
        return render(request, 'update_starting/update_starting.html',{"user":request.user,"team":selected_team,"player":selected_player,"schedule":team_schedule_list})
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_match= get_object_or_404(Match_Starting, starting_schedule__id=request.POST.get("schedule_id"))
        request.POST = request.POST.copy()
        if selected_team == selected_match.starting_schedule.schedule_home:
            request.POST['home_starting'] = request.POST['starting']
            form = MatchStartingForm(request.POST, instance=selected_match)
            if form.is_valid():
                selected_match = form.save(commit=False)
                selected_match.save()
                form.save_m2m()
        elif selected_team == selected_match.starting_schedule.schedule_away:
            request.POST['away_starting'] = request.POST['starting']
            form = MatchStartingForm(request.POST, instance=selected_match)
            if form.is_valid():
                selected_match = form.save(commit=False)
                selected_match.save()
                form.save_m2m()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

**update_starting.html**

```
<div>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <select name="schedule_id">
            {% for x in schedule %}
            <option value="{{x.id}}">{{x.get_schedule_name_display}} {{x.schedule_home}} - {{x.schedule_away}}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        {% for x in player %}
            <input type="checkbox" name="starting" value="{{x.id}}">{{x.player_name}}<br>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="Save">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: what you need for the form is a formset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: the home/away is a simple check in your view that the User belongs to the team for which you're rendering a view.

Comment: I just updated views forms and html. Seems not working. I have no idea how to save manytomanyfield

Answer (score 1):

***How can I generate the form with the Players belongs to Team.***

You first would need a form for players:

```
class PlayerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = '__all__'
```

and then put this into practice: [Django Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/formsets/)

***How to let the User upload Home / Away (The team belongs to User) starting XI only.***

You will need here a form too, this time for the `Schedule` model as well.

@rchurch4 said: *They just want to know how to ensure that the User can only upload the roster for his team*.

If that the case, you only have to be sure in your `Team` list view you only list teams belonging to the authenticated `User`.

Comment: You're overthinking the second part. They just want to know how to ensure that the User can only upload the roster for his team. No form needed, just a view check.

Comment: I just updated views forms and html. Seems not working. I have no idea how to save manytomanyfield